# Using timeout in a sidekiq or activejob perform method

Tags: ruby, concurrency, sidekiq, rails-activejob

I'm planning to move from Heroku Scheduler to a custom clock process using the clockwork gem. Heroku Scheduler will kill a task if it didn't complete before the next scheduled one of the same type.
How do I achieve this in Sidekiq?

Given that Timeout is not thread safe. Is it a bad idea to do this in a Sidekiq worker?

```
class RunsTooLongWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  sidekiq_options :retry => false

  def perform(*args)
    Timeout::timeout(2.hours) do
      # do possibly long running task
    end
  end
end
```

If not what's the alternative? Let's say I want to run a job every 10 minutes but I don't want to have the same jobs running at the same time. How should I deal with that?

Answer (score 0):

To answer this part of your question:

> Given that Timeout is not thread safe. Is it a bad idea to do this in a Sidekiq worker?

Here is a great blog post written by Mike Perham about 
[why you shouldn't use Ruby's timeout module in sidekiq jobs](http://www.mikeperham.com/2015/05/08/timeout-rubys-most-dangerous-api/)

As for an alternative...It sounds like what you need most is to ensure that your jobs don't trip over each other. For this, I can think of two approaches:

- Poor Man's approach: create an 'enqueued' attribute on the model of the object you're working on. When you begin whatever processing you're doing, mark that item as enqueued, and when you finish, mark it as 'not enqueued'. Make your every-ten-minute job scope to those not enqueued. Alternatively, create a new table with your job's name and its a status field, and query it for availability before re-executing your processing.
- If you have something more complex going on, this sounds like a great case for [Sidekiq Unique Jobs gem.](https://github.com/mhenrixon/sidekiq-unique-jobs#while-executing). I think the 'while executing' approach is the one you want.

Answer (score -3):

I guess the solution for your task will be to use `whenever` gem as it is suggested at Sidekiq [wiki](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Scheduled-Jobs) , and this is the [wiki](https://github.com/javan/whenever) for `whenever` after installation it will create `config/schedule.rb`file  where you can define schedule of your jobs for example

```
every 3.hours do
  runner "MyModel.some_process"
  rake "my:rake:task"
  command "/usr/bin/my_great_command"
end
```

it has three build in types as you can see from the snippet `runner, rake and command` but you can also define you owns, and it is explained in wiki as well.

Comment: I've added more context to the question. I'm already using clockwork which is like whenever.